Where did the rotational energy come from?
Consider a floating static pencil in flat space with no gravity. If we apply an impact force F for a short time t to the pencil vertically, pencil must get a CM momentum Ft, and corresponding kinetic energy. Furthermore, if the point we applied the force differed from the pencil’s CM point by z, it also must get an angular momentum zFt, and of course a rotational energy as well, according to the angular momentum. If we compare the z=0 situation with this, it is weird that we applied the same force, but the all energy of the pencil at the final state is different. Why?

Does this answer your question? Energy due to force acting on a rod

Exact duplicate of this question.

Work is force times distance. If the force is applied off-center then the distance over which the force is applied will be larger. So, the additional energy is given by additional work done by the external force.
Although the force is the same in both cases, the distance is not, so the work is different.
